# Spooling Japanese data from oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, spool

I am trying to spool data from database, the data consists of Japanese characters.
Please find the below code that is used for spooling data.

```
set echo off
set verify off
set heading off
set termout off
set feedback off
set pages 0
set linesize 32767

spool "C:\Users\Japanese Data\test1.txt"
select 
'重要な形式のデータ'
from dual;
spool off;
```

I am getting the output as ????????? in the test1.txt file.

Please let me know what changes are to me made to spool the data in correct format.

Comment: have you looked at `test1.txt` in the specified path?

Comment: Yes the data in the output file is '?????????'

Comment: you should change the `nls_language` parameter.what is it currently set to?

Comment: this may help you https://community.oracle.com/thread/2376747?tstart=0

Comment: The nls_language is currently set to  AMERICAN

Comment: How are you viewing the text file?

Comment: I opened it using Notepad++